# Can't connect to Oracle DB in Spring Boot (Cloud App)

Tags: java, spring, oracle, spring-boot

I have a DB connection problem on my Basic Spring Cloud App.

I am using Spring Boot 2.2.11.RELEASE and Oracle 19C. Details here:

[image: Environment]

**Dependency for Oracle JDBC:**

[image: Dependency for Oracle JDBC:]

[image: Datasource URL]

**When starting the application, I've got the following error Message:**

```
2020-11-29 12:30:15.758 ERROR 13160 --- [-192.168.110.46] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.

java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:854) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:793) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:57) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:747) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:562) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:358) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:477) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:560) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:158) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:116) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:79) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:324) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicator.getProduct(DataSourceHealthIndicator.java:122) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.2.11.RELEASE.jar:2.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicator.doDataSourceHealthCheck(DataSourceHealthIndicator.java:107) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.2.11.RELEASE.jar:2.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicator.doHealthCheck(DataSourceHealthIndicator.java:102) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.2.11.RELEASE.jar:2.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.AbstractHealthIndicator.health(AbstractHealthIndicator.java:82) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.2.11.RELEASE.jar:2.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthIndicator.getHealth(HealthIndicator.java:37) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.2.11.RELEASE.jar:2.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint.getHealth(HealthEndpoint.java:81) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.2.11.RELEASE.jar:2.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint.getHealth(HealthEndpoint.java:38) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.2.11.RELEASE.jar:2.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getContribution(HealthEndpointSupport.java:108) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.2.11.RELEASE.jar:2.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getAggregateHealth(HealthEndpointSupport.java:119) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.2.11.RELEASE.jar:2.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getContribution(HealthEndpointSupport.java:105) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.2.11.RELEASE.jar:2.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getHealth(HealthEndpointSupport.java:83) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.2.11.RELEASE.jar:2.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getHealth(HealthEndpointSupport.java:70) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.2.11.RELEASE.jar:2.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint.health(HealthEndpoint.java:75) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.2.11.RELEASE.jar:2.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint.health(HealthEndpoint.java:65) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.2.11.RELEASE.jar:2.2.11.RELEASE]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:282) ~[spring-core-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.invoke.reflect.ReflectiveOperationInvoker.invoke(ReflectiveOperationInvoker.java:77) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.2.11.RELEASE.jar:2.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.AbstractDiscoveredOperation.invoke(AbstractDiscoveredOperation.java:60) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.2.11.RELEASE.jar:2.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.jmx.EndpointMBean.invoke(EndpointMBean.java:121) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.2.11.RELEASE.jar:2.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.jmx.EndpointMBean.invoke(EndpointMBean.java:96) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.2.11.RELEASE.jar:2.2.11.RELEASE]
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:809) ~[na:na]
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801) ~[na:na]
    at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1466) ~[na:na]
    at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1307) ~[na:na]
    at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1399) ~[na:na]
    at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:827) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor108.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:359) ~[na:na]
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200) ~[na:na]
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:691) ~[na:na]
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196) ~[na:na]
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:587) ~[na:na]
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:828) ~[na:na]
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:705) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391) ~[na:na]
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:704) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:571) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.resolveAndExecute(AddrResolution.java:548) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.establishConnection(NSProtocol.java:682) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:309) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1596) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:588) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
    ... 60 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connection refused: connect, socket connect lapse 2020 ms. /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 1251 30000 1 true
    at oracle.net.nt.TcpNTAdapter.connect(TcpNTAdapter.java:233) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnOption.connect(ConnOption.java:174) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:510) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
    ... 65 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:574) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:784) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.nio.channels.SocketChannel.open(SocketChannel.java:224) ~[na:na]
    at oracle.net.nt.TimeoutSocketChannel.connect(TimeoutSocketChannel.java:99) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.net.nt.TimeoutSocketChannel.<init>(TimeoutSocketChannel.java:77) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.net.nt.TcpNTAdapter.connect(TcpNTAdapter.java:192) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
    ... 67 common frames omitted

2020-11-29 12:30:15.762  WARN 13160 --- [-192.168.110.46] o.s.b.a.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicator   : DataSource health check failed

org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:82) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:324) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicator.getProduct(DataSourceHealthIndicator.java:122) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.2.11.RELEASE.jar:2.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicator.doDataSourceHealthCheck(DataSourceHealthIndicator.java:107) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.2.11.RELEASE.jar:2.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicator.doHealthCheck(DataSourceHealthIndicator.java:102) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.2.11.RELEASE.jar:2.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.AbstractHealthIndicator.health(AbstractHealthIndicator.java:82) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.2.11.RELEASE.jar:2.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthIndicator.getHealth(HealthIndicator.java:37) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.2.11.RELEASE.jar:2.2.11.RELEASE]
```

I can connect to Oracle 19C with the above URL in SQL Developer.
Here is a screenshot.

[image]

1. listener.ora
   [image: Listener]
2. tnsnames.ora
   [image: tnsnames.ora]

I tried to use "DESKTOP-KUC7NN8" in connection string as a host name. But same error!

Comment: does this answer your question?http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_network_adapter_could_not_establish_connection.htm

Comment: @priyranjan, I checked things, but everything seems ok.

Comment: haha if everything seems ok then it should work ryt. when you are writing code then nothing is ohk until n unless code works.

Comment: @priyranjan, I attached Oracle configuration files: listener.ora and tnsnames.ora

Comment: Please do not screenshot configuration. In the Windows world this is common, but in the *nix world we don't use our eyes. We use the keyboard. So please update your answer in text format and search for "1251"

Comment: @BjarteBrandt - "and search for "1251"",,, don't you mean '1521' -- the listener port?

Comment: @EdStevens, Thanks, I just found the problem and fixed.

Comment: @priyranjan, port was wrong! not 1251.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a typo in defining the data source URL. Port was wrong!

Wrong: `jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1251/ORCL`

**Correct:** `jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/ORCL`